# Як правильно - "демографічний регістр" чи "демографічний реєстр"?

Tags: значення-слів, вибір-слова, означення

Словопедія [наводить](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53408/25671.html) такі пояснення:

> Регістр (-у)
>
> 1. Ділянка звукового діапазону; **орган державного**
>      **технічного нагляду за будівництвом і безпекою плавання суден**. Звуки
>      нижнього регістру. Діяльність регістру.
> 2. Регістр (-а). Розподільник,
>      регулятор у деяких машинах і приладах; пристрій в обчислювальних
>      апаратах.
>
> Реєстр (-у) – список, письмовий перелік когось, чогось; книга для
>   записування, обліку. Внести до реєстру.

СУМ дозволяє використання `регістру` в контексті "списку/переліку":

> род. у, спец. **Список, перелік чого-небудь**; книга для записування, обліку чогось. Стає траулер самостійною поважною одиницею радянського
>   морського флоту. Його номер, ім'я і тоннажність заносять в усі
>   регістри світу (Вадим Собко, Матв. затока, 1962, 15).

Але потрібно відзначити, що тут йде мова саме про судоплавство, що виглядає як виняток і словопедія і інші джерела це побічно підтверджують.

Вікіпедія [пропонує](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80) наступні значення:

> Регістр літер — див.: велика (заголовна) і мала літера.
>
> Регістр (розкладка) — верхня чи нижня розкладка клавіатури,
>   комп'ютерної чи друкарської;
>
> Регістр (цифрова техніка) — послідовнісний логічний пристрій,
>   мікросхема з таким пристроєм;
>
> Регістр процесора — комірка внутрішньої швидкодіючої пам'яті
>   процесора;
>
> Регістр стану — регістр процесора, що зберігає важливу інформацію про
>   стан обчислювальної системи;
>
> Регістр в музиці
>
> Регістр Ллойда (судноплавний)

Фактично, Вікіпедія заперечує коректність вживання виразу `демографічний реєстр`.

В інтерв'ю з директоркою Інституту демографії та соціальних досліджень імені М.В. Птухи НАН України академіка Елли Лібанової є така цитата:

> Демографічний **регістр** населення існує у більшості країн світу та
>   фіксує всі демографічні події в житті громадян – від народження до
>   смерті. Однак демографічний **регістр** не єдиний – існують також **регістр**
>   ринку праці, що містить інформацію про зайнятість населення, **регістр**
>   отримувачів соціальних трансфертів (включно з пенсіонерами) тощо. В
>   Україні наразі ведуться лише **регістр** пенсіонерів і **регістр** Державної
>   фіскальної служби, яким також користується Пенсійний фонд.

Інші приклади використання `регістру`:

1. [Регістр судноплавства України](http://www.shipregister.ua/)
2. [Про прийняття за основу проекту Закону України про національний демографічний регістр](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/main/485-16)

Але `реєстр` все ж зустрчається частіше:

1. [Єдиний державний демографічний реєстр](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%84%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%94%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80).
2. [Термін «Єдиний державний демографічний реєстр»](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/term/33722).
3. [Про Єдиний державний демографічний реєстр та документи, що підтверджують громадянство України, посвідчують особу чи її спеціальний статус](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/main/5492-17).

На мою думку, використання виразу `демографічний регістр` є не вірним і більшість джерел це підтверджують. Однак, виникає питання, чому СУМ дає не вірні або не точні дані і чому `регістр` використовується в судноплавстві.

Є гіпотеза, що `демографічний регістр` є калькою/запозиченням з російської, зокрема, такий вираз можна зустріти [тут](http://rybakovsky.ru/uchebnik2a10.html).

Питання:

1. Чи є вірним вираз `демографічний регістр` в контексті `реєстру` (списку/передіку) крім судноплавства?
2. Чому `регістр` вживається в судноплавстві?
3. Як пояснити дані з СУМ та назву "Закону України про національний демографічний регістр" - це неточна інформація чи все-таки `демографічний регістр` є коректним виразом?

Comment: Вітаємо з поверненням!

Comment: Хтось ще пам'ятає :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для початку розглянемо **`регістр`** vs **`реєстр`**.

Мені подобається думка пана Романа Мисака, яку він висловлює в аналізі [«Щодо вживання термінів «регістр» і «реєстр» у сучасних українських терміносистемах, зокрема у галузі економічних досліджень»](http://tc.terminology.lp.edu.ua/TK_Answers/TK_answer0009.htm?fbclid=IwAR0Zvj5itmxh-yun_Y7p64lMYnHZBFHwXOi3xdpqqQOF2h-NKElm7M7mHE4) на ресурсі Технічного комітету стандартизації науково-технічної термінології (ТК СНТТ). Пан Мисак, хоч і не є лінгвістом, але з 2010 року обіймає посаду відповідального секретаря ТК СНТТ (ТК 19)  і є автором понад 30 наукових праць в тому числі й у сфері [термінології та термінографії](http://tc.terminology.lp.edu.ua/TK_staff_Mysak_praci.htm).

Роман Мисак, посилаючись на [Банк термінів](http://uas.org.ua/ua/bank-danih/natsionalniy-bank-terminiv/) на веб-сайті Державного підприємства «Український науково-дослідний і навчальний центр проблем стандартизації, сертифікації та якості» ДП «УкрНДНЦ» , зазначає, що

> термін `регістр` та терміносполуки з цим словом `арифметичний регістр`, `індексний регістр`, `накопичувальний регістр` тощо вжито
>   лише як технічні терміни <...>. Терміна `регістрація` український
>   правопис на фіксує. У цьому Банку термін `реєстр` та його похідники
>   вжито у значенні документа, переліку, покажчика, опису <...>.
>   Процедуру внесення до переліку, опису, покажчика позначають як
>   `реєстрація`, `реєстрування` <...>

Пан Роман апелює до Етимологічного словника української мови (К. : Наукова думка, 2006. – Т. 5. – С. 44, 46), цитує низку сучасних фахових словників, які розрізняють терміни `регістр` та `реєстр`, і робить висновок:

> I. Терміни `регістр` і `реєстр` не є синонімами, мають
>   відмінні тлумачення та різну галузеву належність;
>
> II. У галузі економічних досліджень треба вживати термін `реєстр`
>   у значенні: 1) перелік, список, опис; 2) книги, картки, документи.
>   Термін `регістр` у цьому значенні не дозволений для вживання, бо
>   може призвести до спотворення та порушення цілісності терміносистеми.

І хоч я загалом теж вважаю, що слід за можливості уникати омонімізації термінів, і в цьому випадку з регістром зокрема, все ж не можу погодитись з категоричністю п. Мисака щодо «не дозволеності» вжиття терміну `регістр` у значенні «1) перелік, список, опис; 2) книги, картки, документи.»

Все ж СУМ  із позначкою «спец.» містить серед іншого й таке значення [**регістру**](http://sum.in.ua/s/reghistr), щодо якого є сумніви в автора запитання (і в мене також). Та й [ГРАК](http://uacorpus.org/?fbclid=IwAR1KUOqSf8OMtXk48Jn9f-9PHi5bu240dP43G1X_J4czM1AU8tAX3s16Jvk) видає результати вживання `регістру` в означеному контексті.

Можемо тільки припустити, як в СУМ потрапило це значення. Це могло бути з огляду на етимологію іменника і його значення в мові-донорі, про що зазначено й у згаданому Етимологічному словнику української мови.

Щодо причин використання іменника **`регістр`** у галузі судноплавства.

Варто зауважити, що [Регістр судноплавства України](http://www.shipregister.ua/about/index.html), на який дає посилання автор запитання, не є списком/переліком, описом. Це назва державного підприємства.

> ДП "Класифікаційне товариство Регістр судноплавства України" є
>   державним підприємством у галузі морського та річкового транспорту,
>   основні види діяльності якого пов’язані з забезпечення безпеки
>   судноплавства.

І використання в назві підприємства слова `регістр` не є підтвердженням того, що воно тут вжито в значенні *список/перелік/опис*. Навіть [Статут](http://www.shipregister.ua/regulations/statute.pdf) підприємства з-поміж його функцій не містить функції ведення будь-якого чи то регістру, чи то реєстру.

Натомість, бачимо, що Державна служба морського та річкового транспорту України використовує саме термін `реєстр` при наданні послуг  [Державного суднового реєстру України](https://marad.gov.ua/ua/poslugi/derzhavnij-sudnovij-reyestr-ukrayini).

Якщо звернутися до історії вищезазначеного ДП і його попередників, яку докладно описала пані Плачкова Т. М., аспірант кафедри морського та митного права Національного університету «Одеська юридична академія» (м. Одеса, Україна) у статті [«Інституціоналізація системи органів управління безпекою мореплавства в Україні»](http://dspace.onua.edu.ua/bitstream/handle/11300/9161/Plachkova_LP_1_2018..pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), то дійсно Регістр дістався нам у спадок ще від СРСР, коли до системи забезпечення безпеки мореплавства належав Регістр СРСР, що діяв на підставі Постанови РНК СРСР від 11.12.1931 р. № 1127 «Про Регістр Союзу РСР», і через низку нормативних документів ще УРСР (Постанова Ради Міністрів 1991 р.), а потім і незалежної України (Постанова КМУ 1998 р. та ряд пізніших нормативно-правових актів) зберігся в назві класифікаційного товариства.

Утім, припускаю, що вживання саме `регістру` в назві ДП зумовлене не тільки успадкуванням з СРСР і калькуванням з російської, а, ймовірно, і за зразком з [аналогічними структурами в інших країнах](http://www.shipregister.ua/external.html), та, зокрема, найавторитетнішою профільною асоціацією [Регістр Судноплавства Ллойда - Lloyd Register of Shipping](http://leksika.com.ua/17490110/legal/registr_sudnoplavstva_lloyda), до складу якої входять відповідні представництва понад 100 країн.

Нарешті, стосовно **`демографічного регістру`**. Важко сказати, чому автори проекту Закону України про національний демографічний регістр від 2012 року вирішили використати саме цей термін. Не виключаю, що як наслідок калькування цитованих у запитанні російських фахівців з демографії  такими ж російськомовними українськими експертами та навіть поважними академіками.

Проте, вбачається, що здоровий глузд наразі перемагає, оскільки в юридичній площині спеціальним [Законом України  «Про Єдиний державний демографічний реєстр та документи, що підтверджують громадянство України, посвідчують особу чи її спеціальний статус»](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/main/5492-17) закріплений термін `демографічний реєстр`.

Таким чином, на сьогодні **`реєстр`** – найвірогідніше, єдиний термін в значенні *перелік/опис/список*, що вживається на загальнодержавному рівні, про що свідчить [Єдиний державний портал адміністративних послуг](http://my.gov.ua/), де за пошуком `регістр` видає 0 результатів, а `реєстр` – 301.